How to map a texture to faces using geometry normals
In my specific scenario I need to align the roof texture to the individual roofes.
I cannot align the roofes in the UV map because there are too many and its real word data.

My thinking is that I can use the Geometry node and its Normal output to get information about the face orientation,
I then just need to calculate the angle of each face, which I can plug into the Mapping node, resulting in the correct texture rotation for each roof face.
The formula for calculating the angle between two vectors (normals) is θ = cos-1 [ (a · b) / (|a| |b|) ]
I tried to create this formula as a node with the Node Quick Maths extension and with Vector Math nodes. I also figured that I was only interested in the Z rotation, so I only needed X, Y (2D coordinates) in the calculation.


The outcome is not what I expected, there is rotation but the wrong rotation, which leads me to believe that either my math is wrong (which could very well be that I am not that well versed in math or Blender math nodes) or I need to approach this in a whole new direction.
What I would like to happen.

let me know if there are Qustions. Thanks a lot ...

You need to use Z to make this calculation (it's the only axis that does not change with the roof positions)

A cross from Z to Normal makes local X (fails for horizontal roofs, where normal = z)
A cross from Normal to local X makes local Y
A dot between Position and the local axis gives the local position

Important: The texture's "Projection" must be "Flat". This method is similar to UV unwrapping every single face. Any non-flat projection will create distortion.



Thank you!  For those passing by, here's an example file with this solution.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5gi7c1h7dzu3948alpfm2/shingles-roof-direction.blend?rlkey=0sgmyad8526lmb4m5ivsgosj3&st=xuhhs7ky&dl=0

One hiccup i've noticed is that when the angle of the roof is increased past a certain point, a texture based material, stops working as expected.
screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/sx10elye301nqnuylucen/2024-11-05_20-37-23_blendershingles_roof_direction_-DDropboxTroubleshooting20blender.png?rlkey=o6bvh5m053ksia9crbhidii1y&dl=0
test file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5gi7c1h7dzu3948alpfm2/shingles-roof-direction.blend?rlkey=0sgmyad8526lmb4m5ivsgosj3&dl=0

@RyanSchultz, that's because you're using a "box" texture instead of a "flat" texture.

That was it.. thanks!
